# C# ogrinfo with virtual vector source doesn't work GDAL 1.10

Tags: gdal, c#, ogr

I am trying to use GDAL 1.10 with a vector virtual source which is nothing more than the example union of two shapefile layers. from the commandline, ogrinfo works fine on the source. But the C# binding version of ogrinfo cannot open either shapefile.

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to be a path issue.

With the C ogrinfo, I can put the shapefile layer filenames sans path in the OGRVRTLayer. If I then run the C# ogrinfo, it can't find those shapefiles. However, if I put the full path of the shapefiles into the OGRVRTLayer, then both versions successfully read the virtual source.